# How prove this $\dim V=1 \iff \mathbf{A}=a\mathbf{E}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let   $\mathbf{A}\in F^{n\times n}$,and define
$$V=\{f(\mathbf{A})\mid f(x)\in F[x]\}$$

> Show that: $$\dim V=1 \iff \mathbf{A}=a\mathbf{E}$$ where $\mathbf{E}$ is the unit square
>    matrix.

My try:I think this problem we can prove follow two case:

case1:

If 
$$\mathbf{A}=a\mathbf{E} \implies f(\mathbf{A})=f(a\mathbf{E})$$
then we must 
prove 
$$\dim V=1$$

case2:

if
$\dim V=1$,then we must prove 
$$\mathbf{A}=a\mathbf{E}$$

where $F$ field:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

and I can't,Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that if $A=aE$ then $f(A)=f(a)E\in V$ hence $V=\mathrm{span}(E)$ and $\dim V=1$.

Conversely by contraposition if $A\ne a E$  then the family $(E,A)$ is linearly independant hence $\dim V\ge2$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $\dim V=1$ then $A$ and  $E$ must be linaerly dependant. And if $A=aE$ then $f(A)=f(a)E$.

Comment: Hello,why $A$ and $E$ must be linaerly dependant? can you post your  full solution,Thank you